# domain user Access permission as local on AWS from another server

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created a free instance on AWS with windows 2012 and MS DB.

How can I allow user authentication with my Active Directory on premise (my own server with `Windows 2008` and a static IP) on the AWS instance? The MS DB is installed on AWS and access works with a domain user as local.

I don't want to create another Active Directory on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Configure a VPN between AWS and your on-prem AD.

Comment: create VPN on AWS?? but its paid services.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. If you need your cloud-based resources to use your on-premises identities, then you need to configure a VPN between the cloud and your datacenter.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPN_CloudHub.html